# Error occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface"

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am working on STS IDE version 3.9.9.RELEASE.

I am having a Spring Boot Application, the application was running perfectly fine and suddenly a weird thing happened.
Now When I am trying to configure the Run Environment by Clicking on ***Run Configuration***, I am getting below error in Error Logs and I am unable to Run my application.

I am also getting attached pop-up as soon as I click on **Run Configuration**

[image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.newProjectRuntimeClasspathEntry(JavaRuntime.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.InternalModuleSupport.newModularProjectRuntimeClasspathEntry(InternalModuleSupport.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.ModuleSupport.newModularProjectRuntimeClasspathEntry(ModuleSupport.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.computeUnresolvedClasspath(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.RuntimeClasspathProvider.computeUnresolvedClasspath(RuntimeClasspathProvider.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.computeUnresolvedRuntimeClasspath(JavaRuntime.java:1636)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaClasspathTab.createClasspathModel(JavaClasspathTab.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaClasspathTab.refresh(JavaClasspathTab.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaClasspathTab.initializeFrom(JavaClasspathTab.java:239)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch.BootClasspathTab.initializeFrom(BootClasspathTab.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup.initializeFrom(AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupWrapper.initializeFrom(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupWrapper.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.lambda$4(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog$4.selectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.lambda$0(StructuredViewer.java:1263)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3933)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3564)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.lambda$1(DebugUITools.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1064)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1055)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3958)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3561)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:563)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1501)
```

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=3.9.9.201906181641-RELEASE-e49
java.version=1.8.0_102
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -clean
```

**Solution Already Tried**: I have already tried below solutions which didn't worked:

1. I have tried upgrading the STS, it upgraded successfully. However the error still persist. Currently it is on **3.9.9.RELEASE**.
2. I have ran the IDE using command prompt by cleaning the cache as well, application opened properly, however the error still persist:

   STS.exe -clean

**Also find attached the screenshot of the Error Event**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Following Solution worked for me**

1. Removed the project from STS-Eclipse Workspace, by deleting the project from the work space and make sure to not to delete the content of the Project.
2. Again import the project from the same directory.
3. Right Click Project ---> Click on Run As --> Click on Run Configuration ----> Add New Configuration. Now I am able to add new configuration and as well as  Apply Button is also working fine.
4. Previously added configurations are still not working, but newly added configurations are working fine.

**Please let me know if we have any other solution for this problem**